# Google Sheets - Two-way lookup pulling data from multiple sheet tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup, gs-vlookup

I've been working on a sheet where I want to have and input tab and output tab.
The input tab is basically a table and the output tab will be a calendar (of sorts).

In my example:

Sheet1 = input tab

Sheet2 = output tab

I wish to have a vlookup that will pull its search_key from Sheet2 (output) and search it against a range in Sheet1.

I've been messing around with the following (green cell Sheet2 in example):

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$7,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$7,0),False))`

I had also tried a variation of this using hlookup instead of MATCH but didn't have much luck with it.

The problem I have is that I no longer know where to place my column index. In my example sheet I have it working with a one way vlookup (blue cell Sheet2) that returns the desired value from Sheet1 (Length Column) using this index. Is it not possible to do so in the two way lookup??

Here's a link to the example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_nqH-XOxNhQAUVJzesNBZeMci7AV9RowSQUnptAruPc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this function in Apps Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var firstRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet1.getLastRow() - 1;
  var firstCol = 1;
  var numCols = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  var inputData = sheet1.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  var numBrands = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var outputRange = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var outputData = outputRange.getValues();
  // Iterating through each row in Sheet1 data:
  for(var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) { 
    // Iterating through each row in Sheet2:
    for(var j = 1; j < outputData.length; j++) { 
      // Iterates through each cell for each row in Sheet2.
      for(var k = 1; k < outputData[0].length; k++) { 
        var inputBrand = inputData[i][0];
        var outputBrand = outputData[j][0];
        var inputDate = inputData[i][1];
        var outputDate = outputData[0][k];
        // It checks whether the date and brand corresponding to each cell 
        // (same row or column) matches the date and brand in the current 
        // row in Sheet1
        if(inputBrand == outputBrand && inputDate.toString() == outputDate.toString()) {
          var inputLength = inputData[i][2];
          sheet2.getRange(j+1, k+1, 1, 1).setValue(inputLength);
        }      
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks a bunch! I changed it to an onEdit function and it's running perfectly. Would you mind breaking some of this down for me? I understand the variables you created but get lost in the "for" statements. Mainly i'm trying to to wrap my head around how you set the ranges? And without doing anymore work for me, just wanted to quickly ask if you think it's possible to have such a script recognize a date range (start/end dates, perhaps in two columns on Sheet1?) and autofill in the dates between on Sheet2?

Comment: hello @redpandasuit, glad my answer helped you! I edited my response with some comments. I hope they will be useful to understand the function. About the date ranges, yes, I think that would be possible. Please post a new question if you need help for that